# What is the difference between "in umerīs" and "in umerōs"?

Tags: grammar-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, ablative, accusative

In chapter 6 of LLPSI, we have the following  sentence

> Syrus et Lēander duōs saccōs in umerīs portant

While in chapter 9, we have:

> Pāstor laetus ovem in umerōs impōnit.

Why the ablative in the first sentence and the accusative in the second one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*In* + ablative means "in/on something" *while* doing the verb.

*In* + accusative means "into/onto something", i.e. the verb involves moving/transferring something else into/onto the something.

So, Syrus and Leander carried the sacks on their shoulders (while carrying them to Iulius's villa); the shepherd placed the sheep *onto* his shoulders.

Answer (score 4):

…carry sacks in their arms. (Abl. —> no motion happening with the sacks)
…placed the sheep into his arms. (Acc. -> motion happening with the sheep)